# How does Wikipedia determine what country a user is from?

Tags: web-services

My iPhone app utilizes Wikipedia and I wanted to test to see how it works in different countries. I thought I could just use a proxy on my network to fake the country but Wikipedia still seems to redirect to English. If I use an address such as "wikipedia.org/wiki/Dog" it will redirect to "en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dog" instead. Google, while using a proxy, detected I was in Mexico.

Basically, my question is how can I test my apps compatibility with different languages in different countries if it accesses Wikipedia. Why am I not able to trick Wikipedia into thinking I'm in a different country. Am I doing something wrong, or does Wikipedia just not detect the country and always default to English (which doesn't make any sense)?

Comment: That's because Wikipedia is more intelligent than Google, Yahoo et altri: it detects the language your browser is using, not your geolocation. I really hate it when web sites show me a web page in a language I don't speak while I (and my browser) asked for the English version...

Comment: My Guess: IP-adress and info on the ISPs location

Comment: On the contrary, IP addresses and geoloc would yield non-English languages.

Comment: It isn't browser the language. I changed both my iPhone and Mac's system language (which changes the browser language) but it still was in English. What was funny, however, is Google Chrome offered to translate the English page to Spanish, the language I switch the my system to!

Comment: Wouldn't using a proxy fake the IP address and ISP location info? I don't know much about this stuff, so correct me if I'm wrong. Also, couldn't we find out somewhere in the source code how it detects country?

Comment: I think it is a mix of browser language AND cookies. Try wiping out cookies, and set the browser to default to Spanish for instance. I think once you have a cookie set Wikipedia uses this.

Comment: Tried changing language and wiping cookies but still no Spanish. Does it default to "en." for others if they just put "wikipedia.org/wiki/Dog" or something else random.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It most probably uses the `Accept-Language: xxxx` header. If your browser (like mine) sends put a header saying `Accept-Language: en-us`, then Wikipedia does just that -- it sends you the English version. Which is what all multinational sites should do (but don't because they prefer to offset server loads regionally...).

So to test Wikipedia in other languages, you could just replace `en.` with something else, like `es.`, `ja.` etc. However "[ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dog](http://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dog)" does not have a page (of course), and "[es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dog](http://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dog)" does exist but won't give you what you'd expect...

Comment: How can I spoof this? Changing the browser language or using a foreign proxy didn't work.

Comment: Okay, so I realize I can use different languages that way, but I want to make sure my iPhone app, which accesses Wikipedia from it, will go to the right language for the right country instead of always defaulting to English. It would be great if someone in another country could verify that "m.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Special%3ARandom" does not go to the English Wikipedia, but rather their localized one.

Comment: I'm in HK and this redirects me to http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/1938_VFL_Grand_Final

Comment: So it looks like it doesn't detect location. Is the only solution to manually detect the location on the iPhone and then append the correct suffix before the URL?

Comment: That would probably work, except for the not-so-little issue I mentioned about stuff like "ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dog"...

Comment: That worked! I didn't run into the mentioned problem, luckily, because the user types in the term and the app searches their Wikipedia for it. The term is not appended to the URL.

Comment: Goody gumdrops. If this worked, you can accept the answer then :-)